# Updating the data in the php code automatically from the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

This is a part of the php code.

```
$params = array(
    'screen_name' => 'phantom',
    'count' => 5,
    'exclude_replies' => true
);
```

I have a database(mysql) that has a table storing various screen names which keeps on updating with time automatically.  Since I'm running a cron job on this php file containing this code mentioned above I wanted even this code automatically updating and containing all the names from the table automatically. Something like

```
$params = array(
    'screen_name' => 'phantom','tuxseo','deredo',
    'count' => 5,
    'exclude_replies' => true
);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why doesn't the PHP script load the values from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the records from the database and store them in `$params["screen_name"]`.

Comment: How to store them in $params["screen_name"]? I'm not that good with php